# Pass a single ajax variable across two pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have searched and searched through this site and other forums, but so far I have not been able to find a solution to my problem. I have seen how to pass variables through the url from one page to another, but not to a third page. I have this url:

```
$.get(ajaxurl, function() {
          window.location.href = "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/login?id=1&url=" + url;
        });
```

I'm trying to get the value of "url" from this page to the next one, and then to a third page, so that I can redirect the user, using that url, after they have successfully logged in.

Let me know if you guys need more information, I am still learning how to communicate efficiently when discussing my coding problems.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: And what is the problem? You're passing it. Then you don't know how to access it on the other page?

Comment: ... Just do the exact same again in the next page...?

Comment: Include a hidden input element (`<input type="hidden" value="..." />`) as part of the form on the Login page, and set its value to the url. That way the url will be included in the form post. After processing the username & password, you can use the url to redirect the user to the desired page.